# LaTeX on Ubuntu 20.04 giving "overfull \vbox" errors when using \includegraphics, \textwidth

Tags: texlive, ubuntu, texlive-2019

I'm using LaTeX on Ubuntu 20.04 (for details see below). I never really had any trouble, but today I started getting unexpected Badbox warnings when using `\includegraphics`: `Overfull \vbox (10.0pt too high) has occurred while \output is active` (referring to line 1). The document compiles fine apart from that, but the image I'm trying to include doesn't appear, instead there's only a number of quotation marks.

The weird thing is that, up to now, this error seems rather inconsistent:

- Some images work fine as long as I don't give any scaling argument (even if the image is too large to fit on one page), or just `[width=\textwidth]`, but as soon as I try something like `[width=0.8\textwidth]` the error is back and the image is gone. But then smaller widths, like `0.1\textwidth`, or `1cm` work fine again (and give tiny images, as expected, so it's not like LaTeX all of a sudden started confusing decimal points and commas).
- Other images will only be included when I make them very small, like `1cm`
- Documents I wrote earlier still compile without trouble, despite all sorts of images and `[width=whatever\textwidth]` arguments (but copying images from these documents to a new document gives the same problem again).
- EDIT: the image height shouldn't give any problems. The images I tried so far have larger width than height. Moreover, some images do show nicely if I include them at `\textwidth`, but not at `0.8\textwidth`

On my Mac (TeX Live 2016) the exact same documents and images aren't giving any trouble at all, so the problem seems to be related to Ubuntu, or the TeX Live version I'm using there (as far as I know, I've never had any other version than 2019 on this PC, but I'm not entirely sure about that).

I've already tried updating, restarting, deleting log-files, starting from scratch with just the bare minimum in terms of packages, but no success so far.

I'm really sorry about the poor reproducibility of this problem. Has anyone encountered something similar?

EDIT:
Example code (replace example-image-a by similar sized eps image of your choice; this example image isn't giving me any problems):

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

EDIT 2:
Even stranger: when I add a second figure, the same Badbox warning comes up, but now my first figure comes out alright, and the SECOND one fails to show.

For now I'll just give up and switch to my Mac.

```
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.3.1
Copyright 2019 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.37; using libpng 1.6.37
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
Compiled with xpdf version 4.01
```

Comment: sorry it is impossible to diagnose your issue with the information given. Without knowing the initial size just saying you used `[width=0.8\textwidth]` is no information at all, the main issue is what is the _height_ of that? does it fit on a page?. Latex will not simply make the image go, it will give errors or warnings, what warnings do you get in the log?

Comment: try `[width=0.8\textwidth,height=.8\textheight,keepaspectratio]`then it will scale the image to be within the page size in both directions

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle! Sorry, yes, I'm fully aware that it's hard to diagnose my issue. The initial size of the image doesn't seem to make a difference though: as I wrote, even when the image is bigger than the page without scaling, it displays just fine. Only for some seemingly random range of widths it won't show, independent of the image height. I'll try the `\texwidth` + `'textheight` suggestion though.

Comment: Too bad, combining `\textwidth` and `\textheight' doesn't work either (except when I set the width to some tiny value again)

Comment: The image width does not affect where the float is placed, only the image height. If the image is too wide you may get overfull hbox warnings but it will be placed at the same place.

Comment: as I have said the scale factors are no information at all unless you say how big the original image is. It is my code you are describing and if I can not guess what code you are not showing I doubt any one else can and your question is not answerable. It is always possible to make a small complete test document that shows the problem use `\includegraphics[height=???,width=???]{example-image}` and choose the `???` to match the size you get and so reproduce your problem. Then include the complete small document in your question.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'll try to create some minimal example. However, my point is that an image that shows up just fine if I don't scale it at all, or if I include it at `\textwidth`, suddenly fails to show if I scale it to a value SMALLER than `\textwidth` (and that the same image doesn't give any problems on my Mac)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I resolved this issue by completely removing TeX Live 2019 (installed using Ubuntu package manager) and installing TeX Live 2021 directly from CTAN, following these instructions: https://fahim-sikder.github.io/post/installing-texlive-latest-ubuntu/

Still no clue what made TeX Live 2019 stop working though.